# ADB doesn't see device

Tags: android, linux, adb, ubuntu-12.10, xubuntu

-Lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:231d Hewlett-Packard 

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0007 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS451 Fingerprint Reader

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 5986:03b1 Acer, Inc 

Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1058:07a8 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c018 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2207:0010
```

the last one is the one y want to adb connect.

/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2207", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

The device is a pipo s1 tablet and the so: xubuntu quantal. In the same PC can connect my phone without issues.

Please bring me the light.

thanx.

Comment: Have you installed the latest version of android tools? I had this error prior to upgrading.

Comment: provide output of 'lsusb -v -s 2:4'

Comment: I finnaly connected creating ./android/adb_usb.ini file with respective code. Now can adb but cannot see device on fastboot....

Comment: You may need to similarly look into how to tell fastboot to consider an additional VID to be a compatible android device of interest to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead of strings like

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2207", MODE=="0666", GROUP="plugindev"
```

add to /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2207", TEST=="/var/run/ConsoleKit/database", RUN+="udev-acl --action=$env{ACTION} --device=$env{DEVNAME}"
```

It makes adb work on Ubuntu 12.04 with another device in my case.

And of course in ~/.android/adb_usb.ini add string

```
0x2207
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add ATTR{idProduct}=="0010" to the line.

Have a look at this link 
http://pychildren.blogspot.se/2012/12/getting-android-adb-working-with-pipo.html

Regards!
/Thomas

Comment: narrowing down the matching rule would not help