# Cannot connect to adb

Tags: android, linux, adb

I have tried everything to connect my phone to my Ubuntu computer and nothing is working. I have tried 3 different phones (mostly Nexus 4) on MTP and PTP protocols. ADB Debugging is on as well as install from unknown sources. I have connected to adb one time but have never been able to since then. `adb usb`, `adb tcpip` both say device not found (all of these with phone plugged in). `adb devices` shows up empty. `adb connect [IP]` returns "unable to connect to [IP]" (I have adb over network enabled and it works on other computers). When I plug my phone in it doesn't even detect that its connected to a computer no matter what usb port I try.

What else can I try to connect it?

Comment: does the device see USB plugged in, and enters adb mode (on device side)?

Comment: Is there a difference in what `lsusb` shows with the phone connected vs not connected?  Do you have a current version of adb?

Comment: Forgot to mention that, there is no difference in `lsusb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. The cable I was using either has something wrong with it or is only for charging not data transfer. Whatever the case, switching to a different cable solved the problem.

Comment: if you had followed the instructions I linked in my answer - you would have found that in 5 minutes, not a month later.

Answer (score 1):

I outlined all major troubleshooting steps for making `adb` work in linux environment in this [write-up](http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-most-comprehensive-write-up-on-how.html)

Use this command to list all connected devices enumerating either `adb` or `fastboot` interface:

```
find -L /sys/bus/usb/devices -maxdepth 2 -path "*/modalias" -printf "%h\t" -exec cat {} \; | awk -F: '/icFFisc42ip0/ {print $1}'
```

To see serial numbers instead of sysfs paths - add `| xargs -i cat {}/serial`

Answer (score 0):

check if USB rules for device are OK in **/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules**

See this post [ADB doesn't see device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396423/adb-doesnt-see-device)